# error while insert a record to ms access

Tags: c#

I have executed the above query, and I got an error :

```
{System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error. in query expression 
'Select [UserID] from UserDetails'
```

and my sample code is below:

```
OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) values (" + "Select [UserID] from UserDetails" + "," + "Select @@identity" + ");", conn);
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        conn.Close();
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You should put your subqueries between parentheses:

```
"Insert into UserCompanyDetails([UserID],[CompanyID]) values ((Select [UserID] from UserDetails),(Select @@identity))"
```

Comment: while i execute your code i got the error Syntax error. in query expression '(Select @@identity)'

Comment: Then try to use directly @@identity without selecting it.

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:**

Try to save the results of the following queries in variables of their respective datatypes.

```
Select [UserID] from UserDetails
Select @@identity
```

Then you can simply use those variables in your **Main Query String**